# How to add text editor field in user edit profile?

Tags: editor

I need to add a text editor in user editor section exactly like category text editor field that I can display description to user profile in frontend. I found this https://webkul.com/blog/wordpress-custom-fields-user-profile-page/ but this just add a normal contact text field.

Answer (score 0):

I found this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ and it can add any custom field to any section of wordpress panel